# Adding + and - sign while show/hide div

Tags: jquery

I use the following jQuery to show/hide a div. I need to add a '+' and '-' symbol to it. Someone please tell me how to add it

```
function toggleWidgets() {
    $('#secondary h3.widget-title').addClass('plus');

    $('#secondary h3.widget-title').click(function() {


        $(this).toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus').next().toggle(180);
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    toggleWidgets();
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
<aside id="welt_last_tweets-2" class="widget widget_welt_last_tweets">
    <h3 class="widget-title"></h3>
    <div id="welt-welt_last_tweets-2" class="welt-tweet-wrapper">

    </div>
</aside>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would let only toggle one class.

```
$('.plus').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('minus');
});
```

And in your css add a plus image to the title as standard and then swap it out for a minus image when it also has the class of minus. Something like:

```
.plus {
    background: url('images/plus.gif') left center no-repeat;
}
.plus.minus {
    background: url('images/minus.gif') left center no-repeat;
}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
   function toggleWidgets() {  
        $('#secondary h3.widget-title').click(function() {
            if($(this).is('.plus')) 
              $(this).switchClass('plus', 'minus');   
            else
              $(this).switchClass('minus', 'plus');   
        });
    }
```